# Mouse movement: Click the sprite "walks" to point clicked

Tags: c#, mouse, user-input, game-physics

I'm pretty new to C# and XNA and well programing (like I can follow a tutorial but most of the creating it on my own is still really really hard).  Right now I'm going round and round trying to figure out how to do this one "simple" thing.

Here's the idea, its going to be a tower defense game; right now I'm working on bare bone basics.  I've got my little sprite guy who will move around with Keyboard input, now I want to click somewhere on the screen and have him "walk" to that point.  Only I'm lost on the logic.  I can click and he'll jump there with

```
if (aMouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
  Position.X = aMouse.X;
  Position.Y = aMouse.Y;
}
```

From what I've read for other mousing input, I'm thinking I'll need some kind of loop (bool maybe?) that will move the sprite in a direction and will have to run a check to see if he's got to that point yet.  But getting that point after the mouse click and creating that loop, running the check...I'm clueless.

Comment: You have two problems to tackle.  People are answering one of them.  The other is what to do if there are obstacles in your way.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding once you get to that point.

Answer (score 2):

You  need to add some instance variables:

```
Point2D targetPos;
```

And some constants:

```
const Point2D speed;
```

When you run through your Update() loop, update the current position by adding the speed vector to it (in the correct direction of course) until you are within a predefined threshold from the target position (usually the thresholds are calculated from the speed vector - if the distance from the current position to the target position is less than the length of the speed vector, then you're at your position). Using a bool in this case would work well. When you click your mouse set another instance variable (moving) to true, and once you've reached your target position, set moving to false.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I need to go learn more about Point2D and defining the thresholds.

Comment: No problem. I meant logic thresholds. It's just checking if your current position is within a certain distance (threshold) from your target position.

Answer (score 2):

People are answering your question at a very low level.  Sometimes it help to think of the problem at a higher level.

What you need is a type of state management.  The fancy Computer Science term for that is a Finite State Machine.  But don't bother looking that up right now.  It's fairly dry and confusing at first :)

Your character currently has one state - "standing around".  You need to add and process the "walking to destination" state.

> From what I've read for other mousing input, I'm thinking I'll need some kind of loop

You need one loop, called the game loop.  If you're using XNA, you've already got one.  But you're on the right track.

Every time through the game loop, you should process the current state, and check for what are called State Transitions.  That's when you change something in your world from one state to another state.  For example, when you click the mouse, you want the guy to start moving.

In your game loop you check to see if a mouse click just happened.  If it did, then set up some data (where to move to), and tell him to start walking by setting his state to "walking to destination".  Next update, you'll process that state instead.

When your character is in the "walking to desintation" state, you need to update their position, based on the amount of time that passed since the last game update.  In XNA, this is calculated for you.  If you're not using XNA, then you'll have to check yourself.  You might be able to use something like the `Stopwatch` class, and check the `Elapsed` field.

If the character is at the destination, you need to switch them back to the "standing around" state.

If you receive another mouse click, it is up to you if you want the "walking to destination" state to pay attention to it or not.  If you do pay attention to it, you set up the same sort of data as when you transitioned from the "standing around" state.

So, you'll need these variables:

- A timer, to find out the elapsed time since the last game loop (XNA gives it to you)
- The current player state (maybe an `enum`)
- The current player position (a vector)
- The walking speed of the player (a float, probably), measured in units per second (or millisecond)
- Data for the "walking to destination" state - target position (another vector)
- Data related to user input (mouse events that occurred since the last update, the position of those clicks, etc)

The character specific data will be different for each character in your game, so you want a new copy of it for each.  You'll probably want to put it in a class.  The rest of it is more global, so you can keep it separate, or make it part of your game, game loop, input classes, etc (however you choose to organize it).

I won't cover the vector math for how to actually calculate the partial movement stuff, since other people have covered that.  No sense in duplicating those answers.  It basically boils down to making a vector between your current position and the target position, and multiplying/dividing it by your walking speed (to chop it up to the distance moved in a single update).

Comment: Thank you for your response!  This does really help me think about what I need.  I had considered doing a state with enum but I hadn't thought about having it for "standing around" or "walking", I think I can add somethine along those lines easily, I've played with that for something else.  I think that I get the logic of what needs to happen, the syntax is where I feel I'm really stuck.  Do you know of a book or an online toutoral that works with "walking" a sprite to a mouse click?  If I can work through another example I can really get my head around it and adapt it to what I want.

Comment: @Steph: Every tutorial I've seen on the subject (some years ago) either assumed a lot of stuff, was overly generic, or was overly complicated.  Here's one I found off google just now: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management, though it looks like it might be tricky.  It also isn't clear from the description whether it supports low level game state (per entity), or only high level state (such as game menu, game over, pause, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have three things:

1. Current position
2. Desired position
3. Speed to move each 'game tick' // don't know what a game tick is? find out!

You're looking at doing this

[image]

```
// dx, dy are delta x and delta y. It's how far in each direction
// the player must travel
// note, I fixed a typo where they were desired - desired... should be
// desired - current, as they are now
float dx = desiredX - currentX;
float dy = desiredY - currentY;

// d uses the pythagorean theorum to find the distance between current and desired
float d = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
// fac is how far along that line between desired and current will you move
float fac = d / speed;

// mx is the component of the dx line proportional to the size of fac : d
// which means it's how far in the x direction you'll move
float mx = dx * fac;
float my = dy * fac;

// the new postition is the old position plus the move value
float newPositionX = dx + mx;
float newPositionY = dy + my;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I have current position and speed, I want the desired postion to come from the user input from the mouse. I'm not sure how to get that from mouse-user-input. I get the picuter, but I don't understnad your code and math here... (I'm really new to all this) In this example your setting the disred position and then moving from current to desired factoring in speed? Why is dx the desiredx minuse the desiredx? and what does sqrt and fac? Sorry! You dont' have to eplaine it all if you don't want to!  I'd like to understand, but I know i'm out of my depth here.

Comment: P.S. I drew that picture myself. Yeah... I contract out my sprite development!

Comment: Ah!!  I see.  Thank you so much for explaining that!! I really apreasheate your help (and I totaly know what you mean about drawing sprites, my guy right now is a squaris block bloby thing :p).

Comment: No problem. Game development is very fun, but there is a lot of math involved. I watch the `game-development` tag, so be sure to include it if you ask any more questions. And if this ever gets playable, send a link :}

Comment: lol.  Will do!  At this rate it might be a VERY long time before it's playbalbe.  I have another question about this math, is it absolutly nessisary to calcluate the distance?  I'm thinking that eitehr the distance needs to be calcuated, or there has to be a bool loop to check to see if the desired (X,Y) has been reached...  Am I thinking along the right lines?  I'm not a fan of math and am always tring to avoid it but with a fromula like this, it would be set once and then it would just run as nessisary...and I'm think that processing wise this would be faster then a bool loop?

Comment: (sorry to keep pestering you) When I punched all this in "sqrt" wasn't working.  I get "The name 'sqrt' does not exist in the current context", so I tried "Math.Sqrt" and get "Cannont implicity convert type 'double to 'float'. and explicit converstion exists (are you missing a cast?)". I'm using XNA 3.0 in MS Visual C# 2008.  I can set up a converstion but think there must be a simpler way...

Comment: I'll walk through these one at a time. 1) an if statement to determine `if(d < speed)` will determine if the player would reach the point. 2) sqrt may well take a double. In that case, use doubles for your coordinates, or cast the result to a float like `float d = (float)sqrt((double)(dx*dx + dy*dy));`

Comment: I'm curious - could you give me an example of a "bool loop"? :-) Do you mean "if statement"? Just so we're on the same page

Answer (score 0):

I have found this code to be most useful... additionally I have added an extra couple lines to prevent certain situations from occuring. For instance there will be times where direction is 0.83 and speed may have been modified by game factors like terrain/wheather/etc.... if speed is below 1, the sprite may not move at all or even move in the wrong direction!

```
 if (Vector2.Distance(Position, TargetPosition) > 2.0f)
 {
    velocity = Vector2.Subtract(TargetPosition, Position);
    velocity.Normalize();
    /// Now no matter which direction we are going we are always moving @ sprite.Speed
    /// at velocity or speed below 1 - problems occur where the unit may not move at all!!
    if(current_Speed < 1)
    {
       Vector2 temp = (velocity * 10) * (current_Speed * 10);
       Position += temp / 10;
    }
    else
    { 
       Vector2 temp = velocity * current_Speed;
       Position += temp;
    }
    //convert to int to render sprite to pixel perfect..
    Position = new Vector2((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y);
 }
```